# Testing function which works with file using mock or fake

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, tdd

I want to test this function:

```
int Info::readFile(string name, StringList infoStrList)
{
    S_File* file = new S_File(name);
    file->getAllLines(infoStrList);
    delete file;
    if(infoStrList.getCount()<=0)
        return ERR_CODE();
    else
        return 0;
}
```

but as there is no file I think I should do it using `fake` or `mock` but as the file object is created in this function I thought I can't use `injection`.
I appreciate any example test code for such situation.

Comment: _but as the file object is created in this function I thought I can't use injection_ - then you need to re-design you method/class

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the code that reads the data from the file away from the logic and then fake that code, using injection of some sort to inject the file read code.